# How to use boost::error_info correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to following the examples on this page:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/motivation.html

The minute I try the following line:

```
throw file_read_error() << errno_code(errno);
```

I get an error:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'errno_code'
```

How do I get this to work??

Ideally I want to create something like this:

```
typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_HRESULTErrorInfo, HRESULT> HRESULTErrorInfo;
```

But I can't even get the first examples to work.

**Edit: Here is a brief example of what generates error C2440 for me:**

```
struct exception_base: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception { };
struct io_error: virtual exception_base { };
struct file_read_error: virtual io_error { };

typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_errno_code,int> errno_code;

void foo()
{
    // error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'errno_code'
    throw file_read_error() << errno_code(errno);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete minimal example you are trying to compile when getting the C2440 error?

Comment: View the example on the link. I couldn't get `throw file_open_error() << errno_code(errno);` to work.

Comment: For others encountering this: the "motivation" page in the Boost Exception docs is incomplete -- a better example is here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_transporting_data.html, where they list the correct headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sam Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782174/how-to-use-boosterror-info-correctly/3783052#3783052) gave me a clue as to what the problem was. I just needed to include:

`#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>`

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why the hell has the correct answer been downvoted?? That #include fixes the code that I posted above.

Comment: An example of a template-related error for which the compiler error message is totally unrelated to the cause of the issue.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 17):

```
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

#include <boost/throw_exception.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

typedef boost::error_info<struct my_tag,std::string> my_tag_error_info;

int
main()
{
    try {
        boost::throw_exception(
                boost::enable_error_info( std::runtime_error( "some error" ) ) 
                << my_tag_error_info("my extra info")
                );
    } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        if ( std::string const * extra  = boost::get_error_info<my_tag_error_info>(e) ) {
            std::cout << *extra << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

produces

```
samm@macmini> ./a.out 
some error
my extra info
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
#include <boost/exception/error_info.hpp>
#include <errno.h>

throw file_read_error() << boost::errinfo_errno(errno);
```

even better:

```
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(file_read_error() << errinfo_errno(errno));
```

Your HRESULTErrorInfo example seems correct.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I had the << outside of the BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION().