# Catching exceptions from boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Stupid question (but I don't find anything on boost.org): how do I catch exceptions from boost::program_options? Invoking

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    bool opt;
    namespace bpo = boost::program_options;
    bpo::options_description options("Allowed options");
    options.add_options()
        ("opt", bpo::bool_switch(&opt));

    bpo::variables_map options_vm;
    try {
        bpo::store(bpo::parse_command_line(argc, argv, options), options_vm);
        bpo::notify(options_vm);
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with any option but `--opt` yields

```
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::program_options::unknown_option>: unrecognised option '--optnsdf'
```

Why doesn't `catch(const std::exception &e)` catch the exception? How do I properly catch catch(const boost::wrapexceptboost::program_options::unknown_option& e)`is not intended, also because there can be other program options-related exceptions, such as`boost::wrapexceptboost::program_options::invalid_command_line_syntax`, and probably others.

Is there any class hierarchy for boost program options exceptions available online?

Comment: Boost isn't inheriting `std::exception`. As for how, the error message tells you exactly what exception gets thrown.

Comment: If you don't care what you're catching, you can `catch(...)`.

Comment: The bigger issue appears to be that you are attempting to use an option that you never added.

Comment: @sweenish What do you mean? It is standard behaviour that programs display a help message if one specifies invalid command line arguments. I want to provide the same behaviour.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. And this is a case where the documentation does tell you what to do. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.30.6.9 And not every program chooses to display a help message on unrecognized options.

Comment: Now we're getting close to duplicate territory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136534/how-to-properly-catch-std-and-boost-exceptions

Comment: @sweenish Yes, but only close. I try to rephrase: Do all exceptions related to command line options parsing have a common base class that I can catch? Is there a class hierarchy available somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly catch std and boost exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136534/how-to-properly-catch-std-and-boost-exceptions)

Comment: @sweenish No; I'd like to capture only those exceptions that come from `boost::program_options`, and not all boost exceptions in full generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the base exception class `program_options::error` by reference:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/450245f7ccfbd9a4)**

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main() {
    std::array argv{"demo", "--oops", static_cast<char const*>(nullptr)};

    po::options_description options("Allowed options");
    bool opt;
    options.add_options()("opt", po::bool_switch(&opt));

    po::variables_map vm;
    try {
        store(parse_command_line(argv.size() - 1, argv.data(), options), vm);
        notify(vm);
    } catch (po::error const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        options.print(std::cerr);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
unrecognised option '--oops'
Allowed options:
  --opt
```

Although there's no diagram there is a kind of error reference: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/program_options/reference.html#header.boost.program_options.errors_hpp

The individual types do mention purpose e.g.: ["Base class for all errors in the library"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/error.html#:%7E:text=Base%20class%20for%20all%20errors%20in%20the%20library))

Comment: The fact that this did not work on my machine (Mac with Homebrew llvm) brought me to the real issue: when linking with `-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++`, your code fails. When linking without this (which libc++ am I linking to then?), then your (and my) code runs as expected. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Addendum:" I have little knowledge of how linking works. Is it possible that `libboost_program_options.a` is built for one libc++, and then linking my program against another libc++ breaks inheritance?

Comment: @Bubaya Probably [ODR violations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (including conflicting RTTI records in different linked objects). There may be more instances of [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as a consequence, so check your build methods closely! Technically it's not "breaking inheritance", just UB